# Inserting a banner in VIM using single keystroke

Tags: vim, header

I was trying to setup a custom header for my vim files.For this I added the below shown code into the **vimrc** file.I want to get the **Modified date** in the header.How can I add that??

After inserting this I want the Vim tobe in the insert mode.And if possible near the **Description**.Is there any way to achieve this???

```
""""""""""""""""""""""
function FileHeading()
  let s:line=line(".")
  call setline(s:line,"/*********************************************")
  call append(s:line,"* Description - ")
  call append(s:line+1,"* Author - ABCD EFG")
  call append(s:line+2,"* Created Date - ".strftime("%b %d %Y"))
  call append(s:line+3,"* Modified Date - 
  call append(s:line+4,"* *******************************************/")
  unlet s:line
endfunction

imap <F4> <Esc>mz:execute FileHeading()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: You're re-inventing functionality for boilerplate header / snippet insertion that is already provided (in a more robust way) by several plugins. Search for them on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/).

#### Snippets

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

#### Update modified time

To update the modification time, you need to hook into the `BufWritePre` event via an `:autocmd`, and `:substitute` the corresponding header line with the updated time. You can use my [AutoAdapt plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4654) for that. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)

Answer (score 0):

As Ingo mentioned snippets are the way to go for this kind of needs. The exact functionality you are looking for it available in both SnipMate and UltiSnips plugin for Vim. I suggest UltiSnips and perhaps the best resource for it may be the [5 minute VimCasts video](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-ultisnips/). Do checkout.